# Define object in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug

I write some script for sum 3 numbers with express and jade...

on index.jade i have a 3 fields and submit button:

```
!!! 5
html
  head
    title Test
  body
    form(name='form1', method='post', action='')
      label(for='1')
      input#1(type='text', name='1')
      label(for='2')
      input#2(type='text', name='2')
      label(for='3')
      input#3(type='text', name='3')
      input(name='submit', type='button', value='submit') 
    span #{result}
```

and on serverside (js code- node.js) I have this code:

```
var express = require('express');
        app = express.createServer();

app.configure(function(){
    app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
    app.set('view engine', 'jade');
    app.use(express.bodyParser());
    app.use(express.methodOverride());
    app.use(app.router);
    app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
});
app.use(express.bodyParser());
    app.get('/', function(req, res){
     res.render('index');
    });


    app.post('/', function(req, res){
      var i = req.param('1', null);
      var j = req.param('2', null);
      var k = req.param('3', null);
      var r = i+j+k;
      res.render('index', {result:r});

    });
app.listen(3010);
```

but every time I start the js file via node app.js I goy message that the object is not defined and some errors in jade file:

How to define object in app.js file?

error:

```
ReferenceError: C:\Users\PC\glowing-frost-5319/views/index.jade:14
    12. '      input#3(type=\'text', name='3')
'
    13. '      input(name=\'submit', type='button', value='submit') 
'
    14. '    #{result}'

result is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (eval at <anonym... etc.
```

Anybody can tell me how to define object result and how to show on index.jade page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to pass result in the second parameter to the render method in your `get` route (just as you are already doing in the `post` route).

Try this:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.render('index', {result: ''});
});
```

This will make the `result` variable available in your view (with a value of empty string in this example).

Comment: also i try:     res.render('index', {result: 0});

Comment: The missing layout is a separate issue. If you don't have a layout then passing layout: false to the render method will render your view without one. If you have no layout at all then you can set this as an application wide view option with app.set('view options', {layout: false}); You can find out more about view layouts at http://expressjs.com/guide.html#view-rendering .

Comment: when I click on submit, nothing happend! WHY?

Comment: so click on submit button to sum 3 numbers and nothing happend ... must write result into span...

Comment: maybe becouse submit is not call/

Comment: The form is not getting submitted because you don't have a submit button. You should change input(name='submit', type='button', value='submit') to input(name='submit', type='submit', value='submit')